# Why would I want to use a custom RNG for Array#shuffle?

Tags: ruby, random

The documentation for [`Array#shuffle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) states:

> `shuffle(random: rng) → new_ary`
>
> The optional `rng` argument will be used as the random number generator.
>
> ```
> a.shuffle(random: Random.new(1))  #=> [1, 3, 2]
> ```

What does that mean and why would I want to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally the `Array#shuffle` method needs a source of random numbers. When you provide the optional RNG parameter, you are telling the method to use that object as the data source.

It is *not* directly for reproducibility. By default `.shuffle` uses the shared `Kernel#rand` RNG and this can be seeded using `srand`.

You can reproduce shuffles as follows:

```
srand(30)
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6].shuffle
# => [3, 1, 2, 0, 4, 6, 5]

srand(30)
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6].shuffle
# => [3, 1, 2, 0, 4, 6, 5]
```

If all you need is repeatability for tests, then `srand` will cover your needs.

So what *is* it for?

Shuffling an array requires a source of random numbers in order to work. By allowing you to over-ride the default `Kernel#rand`, the design allows you control over how these are sourced. Other functions that require a source of randomness also allow similar over-rides e.g. `Array#sample`.

Having this level of control allows you to build shuffled arrays arbitrarily, and separately from any other parts of your code that rely on sources of random numbers. Reproducible output is one useful outcome, with the addition of *independence* from other parts of a program using random numbers that may or may not need reproducible results, or may run at different times that you cannot control.

In addition, for shuffling algorithms there is [a problem creating an even distribution when you have a long list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Pseudorandom_generators:_problems_involving_state_space.2C_seeding.2C_and_usage). If you are shuffling N items you need `factorial(N)` or N! possible unique lists of numbers to come from your RNG, otherwise it cannot possibly produce all allowed arrangements. For Ruby's built in RNG, this limit occurs when shuffling around 2000 items in theory - provided the `srand` value has been chosen from a high quality original random source. You can do better by using an RNG that has has an even higher limit, or a "true" RNG that sources its data from a physical system.

Answer (score 4):

optional `rng` argument will create a fixed random pattern.

Lets try `shuffle` without `rng` argument, we should get different random patterns:

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3 ] 
a.shuffle
# => [3, 2, 1]
a.shuffle
# => [2, 3, 1]
```

Now with `rng`:

```
a.shuffle(random: Random.new(1))
# => [1, 3, 2] 
a.shuffle(random: Random.new(1))
# => [1, 3, 2]
```

As you can see the shuffled array will always contain the same Random pattern -`[1, 3, 2]` in this case.

**why would I want to do that?**

(*As mentioned in comments below*)

Reproducible random is very valuable. It comes handy in tests, games etc.

Comment: Reproducible random is very valuable. In games, etc. :)

Comment: Reproducible random comes in handy in tests, too.

Comment: thanks sergio and spickermann. I didn't answer that part, thanks for helping out with your comments :)